# Run Batch with Drag-and-Drop Parameter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, drag-and-drop

I have a batch program where I can drag-and-drop a file from my pendrive, and it will copy it onto my computer.  I want to create a function in PowerShell (that I will save to the `$profile` document) so that I can do this in powershell

```
>>copy-from-pendrive "file-path"
```

Where `"file-path"` is the path to the file I want to copy.

I know that I can start batch files with `start batch.bat`, but how can I pass a parameter in it?

Here is the code for the batch file

```
@echo off
if [%1] EQU [] (set /p from="From: ") else (set from=%1)

set from=%from:"=%
set from=%from:E:\Elliot\=%

echo from E:\Elliot\%from% to D:\Users\Elliot\%from%" & echo.

xcopy "E:\Elliot\%from%" "D:\Users\Elliot\%from%" /i /s /e /y

echo.
```

Comment: With `set from=%from:"=%` you want to remove surrounding quotes from this variable? But what is your question and what has to with PowerShell (if it is `how can I pass a parameter in it`)?

Comment: @double-beep Yes, sorry.  I forgot the question mark there.  My question is how I could do `start batch.bat` and specify the file path as the `%1` parameter in line 2 of the batch program.  And I want to do this in powershell.

Comment: To trim (outer) double quotes from an argument use the `~` modifier. `if "%~1"=="" (set /p from="From: ") else (set "from=%~1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [param](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-args.html) feature to require a parameter of a file path, then use Copy-Item the same as you do in the batch file:

```
 param(
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String]$path
 )
 copy-item -path $path -destination 'D:\Users\Elliot'
```

Comment: I hadn't though about just making a powershell function to do what my batch file did.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up making the function like this:
`function copy-from-pendrive ($path) {
    $destination = $path.Trim("E:\Elliot")
    copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose -Path "$path\*" -Destination "D:\Users\Elliot\$destination"
}` to get everything working the way I wanted it to.